# Watch video or play games on two external monitors

Tags: display, video, macbook-pro

I have a 2013 15inch retina MacBook Pro and two Dell U2414H as external monitors. I want to watch video or play games like the image in this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66460/how-can-i-set-diablo-3-to-work-across-3-monitors-in-eyefinity-6016-x-1080-res). For the current mac system, I can only achieve two individual external monitors not like the dual monitors. I tried to install Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro, and it can become the dual monitors. However, when I tried to play some video, it can only be displayed on one monitors. Can anyone help me with the issue?

Comment: Have You tried to disable “Displays have separate Spaces” in Mission Control pref pane?

Comment: Which cable you use to connect the monitor?
I have same mac and monitor, but don't work with DP-miniDP cable.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek yes, I tried that. It gives me two same display (mirror) for my two external monitors.

Comment: @Kit I bought an extra dp to dp cable, and it works but not the way I want.